# Confusion about when to use prototype in Crockford's example of Pseudoclassical Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

In Douglas Crockford's *JavaScript: The Good Parts*, he explains the idea of Pseudoclassical inheritance with this piece of code, which shows `Cat` inheriting from `Mammal`.

```
var Cat = function (name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.saying = 'meow';
};
    // Replace Cat.prototype with a new instance of Mammal

    Cat.prototype = new Mammal();

    // Augment the new prototype with
    // purr and get_name methods.

    Cat.prototype.purr = function (n) {
        var i, s = '';
        for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
            if (s) {
               s += '-'; 
            }
            s += 'r'; 
         }
         return s; 
    };

    Cat.prototype.get_name = function () { 
        return this.says() + ' ' + this.name +
                ' ' + this.says();
    };

var myCat = new Cat('Henrietta');
var says = myCat.says(); // 'meow'
var purr = myCat.purr(5); // 'r-r-r-r-r' var name = myCat.get_name();
// 'meow Henrietta meow'
```

Then he introduces a new method called 'inherits' to help make the code more readable.

```
Function.method('inherits', function (Parent) { 
   this.prototype = new Parent();
   return this;
});
```

He shows the example again using the new 'inherit' method.

```
var Cat = function (name) {
         this.name = name;
         this.saying = 'meow';
     }.
         inherits(Mammal).
         method('purr', function (n) {
             var i, s = '';
             for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
                 if (s) {
                     s += '-';
        }
        s += 'r'; 
    }
    return s; 
    }).
    method('get_name', function () {
        return this.says() + ' ' + this.name + ' ' + this.says();
});
```

It looks to me like in this new example, `purr` and `get_name` are defined directly on the `Cat` object, whereas in the first example they were defined on `Cat.prototype`. Is that right? If so, why didn't he define his new methods on `Cat.prototype`? Does it make a difference?

Comment: Uh, are you sure he did `Cat.prototype = new Mammal();` (without explaining how it is wrong)? I thought he'd knew better.

Comment: In the previous chapter (Ch 4), he calls classically inspired syntax "the worst of both worlds" and says that "Use of this style [meaning the `new` keyword] of constructor functions is not recommended. We will see better alternatives in the next chapter."

Comment: Take this book with some amount of salt. For efficiency's sake, I'd actually recommend throwing out the book and just keeping the salt, it's more applicable to modern JS (or really any JS that Crockford didn't write himself).

Comment: Books you'd recommend instead? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `purr` and `get_name` are defined directly on the `Cat` object, whereas in the first example they were defined on `Cat.prototype`. Is that right?

No. While he calls the `method` method on the `Cat` function, it does define methods on the `.prototype` property of the receiver. Maybe turn back a few pages and have a look at the code for `Function.prototype.method` again:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};
```

> Does it make a difference?

Yes, it would.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the code from the book for the `method` method to make the answer more self-contained. Hope that's OK!

Comment: @MichaelGeary Very OK!